# How to you pull all files in project per version or label in Vault?

Tags: sourcegear-vault

I'm new to vault and not a huge fan so far, but I need to do something which would be easy in SVN or Mercurial but I can't figure out how to in Vault.

I need to Get a copy of the repository files as they were at a specific version. I've tried listing thei history and doing a get on a version, but that seems to only get the files that were checked in at that version.

How do I get the whole repository as it was at that version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use labels on folders and files to set a "version", then in vault right-click on the folder/files, choose "show labels", and "check out" this label. For more reading, see the vault documentation on labels at http://download.sourcegear.com/misc/vaultpro/help/client/vaultprohelp.html

Answer (score 0):

Within the Vault client:

1. Right-click on the directory you wish to have in its entirety at a given point in time
2. "Show History"
3. Select radio button "View folder history by version"
4. Make other settings, such as how far back you wish to go, hit "OK"
5. Mark "Version" you want, select "Get Tree"

The only feasible option will be to overwrite in place, so you may want to change the working directory at this point.